# JSF <f:ajax doesn't work correctly with tomahawk <t:selectOneRadio in layout="spread"

Tags: ajax, jsf, tomahawk, selectoneradio

I have a problem using f:ajax with t:selectOneRadio in layout="spread"

Without layout="spread", this is working :

```
<t:selectOneRadio  id="test" value="#{bean.type}" >
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="yes" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="no" itemValue="0"/>
      <f:ajax render="label" />
</t:selectOneRadio>


<h:panelGroup id="label" layout="block">
   <h:outputText value="OK" rendered="#{bean.type == 1}"/>
   <h:outputText value="KO" rendered="#{bean.type == 0}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

When i click on a radio, the text is modified, my type attribute is set in my bean as expected.
My bean is :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {


    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

But With layout="spread", my bean is not set, the setter is not call, but the render works (to test it, inscpect the html, write foo in the div with id="label" and after clicking a radio the text is clear because of the render.

My code with layout="spread" :

```
    <t:selectOneRadio  id="test" value="#{bean.type}" layout="spread">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="yes" itemValue="1"/>
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="no" itemValue="0"/>
          <f:ajax render="label" />
    </t:selectOneRadio>

    <div><t:radio id="radio1" for="test" index="0"/></div>
    <div><t:radio id="radio2" for="test" index="1"/></div>


    <h:panelGroup id="label" layout="block">
       <h:outputText value="OK" rendered="#{bean.type == 1}"/>
       <h:outputText value="KO" rendered="#{bean.type == 0}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

I have tomahawk2.1 in version 1.1.14 and JSF myfaces 2.2.8

Comment: note that the same thing with primefaces is working (layout=custom)